# Discrepancy in tracking data on GA & on my server

Tags: php, android, google-analytics

I have an android app where i am tracking clicks on various buttons On Google analytics as well as on my server on amazon.
Buttons usually redirect users to browser to open a url. Url is my redirect tracking url from my server which once hit redirect user to actual url.

When user click on any button, event is also being tracked on GA.

Its been 2-3 months by now & didn't received same clicks on my server & on GA.

GA usually have almost double clicks than my server tracking. Sometimes difference is quite minor & sometime its even less than the tracked clicks on my server.

```
Example stats :
Date              GA                  Server     
1 FEB             5096                2013
2 FEB             4012                1609
3 FEB             6012                6049
```

Why there is that much difference in the tracked data everyday?
On my tests with single app use i am getting almost same clicks tracked on GA & on my server.

```
Below are some reasons i could think of :

- GA is tracking events even if internet is off for a user. On the other hand Our server could not track events without internet.
- If user click multiple times fastly then GA might be recording events & our server is not. Although with single app i couldn't get this reproduce. 
- User close the browser before the url hit , But GA track that still.
```

I am not able to find exact cause for this. I also verified that code for GA have been implemented correctly.I understand there could be minor difference, but why sometimes more than double?

Please help me to solve this discrepancy puzzle.